# Unable to get rid off this "The 2 extension(s) below, in workspace recommendations have issues" message in VS Code

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am on Mac M1 and the VS Code version installed is 1.67.0

Here is the screenshot:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIGIk.png)

How to get rid of it?

I have tried to restart the VS Code multiple times but the message pops out every time when I start the program. I can dismiss it, but it will reappear when I will open it next time.

I don't see any of those plugins in my installed extensions in VS Code. I have looked in settings.json file as well and no mention about them there as well.

Any idea how to get rid of that message?

Answer (score 5):

In .vscode folder inside your project there should be a file named `extensions.json`,
just get rid of the 2 items:  `"johnsoncodehk.volar"` and `"johnsoncodehk.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin"` from the "reccomandation" array

Comment: The problem is that for some weird reason, Vue team is shipping the install with a .vscode folder that contains a reference to those two extensions. It seems weird that they haven't noticed that those two files are not in the VS Marketplace extension store.

Comment: True story, but getting rid of the 2 items did solve your warning?

Comment: This also fixed the warnings for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This message is showing up because the extensions have been removed from the marketplace. To remove them from your vs code setup you will have to delete them from your VS Codes settings.json file.

1. Open app preferences
2. Search for 'Extensions'
3. Scroll down until you find
   [Settings Sync: Ignored Extensions section in VS Code settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXkVo.png)
4. Alternatively click the
   [Document button on the top right of the window in VS Code Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DucX.png)
5. Remove the lines relating to 'johnsoncodehk' in the top section of 'settings.json'

For reference, I use a Macbook Air M1 and VS Code daily, so I feel your pain with extensions, but I hope this answer helps.

Have a great day :)

Comment: Oh, it has nothing to do with VS Code. In the Vue project in README.md there is Recommended IDE setup paragrpah and there are those two extensions mentioned. It's pretty weird that nobody from the Vue team removed those lines. It's kind of sad. Perhaps switching to React is what I have to do ;(.

Comment: Ahh ok, I personally is React and I have very limited experience with Vue but it makes sense tbh as I have seen a few outdated dependencies with Vue before. Hence my usage of React. Glad you found the issue though :)